# Can I write this as a wrapper?

Tags: python, wrapper, python-decorators

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

class Basis(object):

def __init__(self, dimension):
    self.dimension = dimension

def coord(self, c):
    if self.dimension <= 2:
        return c
    else:
        return c + [0]*(self.dimension-2)

@property
def zerocoord(self):
    return self.coord([0,0])                  

@property
def Dcoord(self):
    return self.coord([1,0])

@property
def Tcoord(self):
    return self.coord([0,1])

@property
def Xcoord(self):
    return self.coord([1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)])

@property
def Ycoord(self):
    return self.coord([-1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)])
```

where all the properties are basically each of the properties is calling the same method `coord`. This is because the actual array that I feed `coord`, `[0,0], [1,0], [0,1]` etc. is fixed, but might be extended depedning on the instance attribute `dimension`.

I am a bit new at Python, but intuitively (and maybe naively) I think this can be written as a wrapper... so something like:

```
@property
def coord(self)
```

and

```
@coord
def Dcoord(self)
```

Which would make the code a bit more elegant.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: You want to alias `property` as `coord`? Just add `coord = property` before your class definition. Otherwise it makes no sense as each of these functions is obtaining something different from `self.coord` so you cannot have a universal wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own descriptor called `Coord`, instead of using `property`.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

class Coord(object):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.foo = [p1, p2]

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj.dimension > 2:
            return self.foo + [0 for x in range(2, obj.dimension)]
        else:
            return self.foo


class Basis(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.dimension = d

    zerocoord = Coord(0, 0)
    dcoord = Coord(1, 0)
    tcoord = Coord(0, 1)
    xcoord = Coord(1/np.sqrt(2), 1/np.sqrt(2))
    ycoord = Coord(-1/np.sqrt(2), -1/np.sqrt(2))
```

Now, the logic for determining the shape of each type of coordinate is embedded in the descriptor itself, rather than your class.

Some examples:

```
>>> Basis(1).dcoord
[1, 0]
>>> Basis(3).dcoord
[1, 0, 0]
>>> Basis(4).tcoord
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the property names and their respective constant values to pass to the `coord` method in a sequence of tuples and then use a loop to set the properties accordingly:

```
class Basis(object):

    def __init__(self, dimension):
        self.dimension = dimension

    def coord(self, c):
        if self.dimension <= 2:
            return c
        else:
            return c + [0]*(self.dimension-2)

for name, value in ('zerocoord', [0, 0]), ('Dcoord', [1, 0]), ('Tcoord', [0, 1]), ('Xcoord', [1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)]), ('Ycoord', [-1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)]):
    setattr(Basis, name, property(lambda self, value=value: self.coord(value)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get rid of a lot of the boilerplate code by doing things this way:

```
import numpy as np

class Basis(object):

    def __init__(self, dimension):
        self.dimension = dimension

    def coord(self, c):
        return c if self.dimension <= 2 else (c + [0]*(self.dimension-2))

    def _coord_prop(loc):
        @property
        def prop(self):
            return self.coord(loc)
        return prop

    zerocoord = _coord_prop([0, 0])
    Dcoord = _coord_prop([1, 0])
    Tcoord = _coord_prop([0, 1])
    Xcoord = _coord_prop([1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)])
    Ycoord = _coord_prop([-1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)])

    del _coord_prop  # Only used inside class definition.

basis = Basis(2)
print(basis.zerocoord)  # -> [0, 0]
print(basis.Dcoord)     # -> [1, 0]
print(basis.Tcoord)     # -> [0, 1]
print(basis.Xcoord)     # -> [0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475]
print(basis.Ycoord)     # -> [-0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a decorator that wraps those methods by calling the `coord` method for them and turning them into properties, so that those methods only need to return the relevant constants instead:

```
def coord_property(func):
    def wrapper(self):
        return self.coord(func(self))
    return property(wrapper)

class Basis(object):

    def __init__(self, dimension):
        self.dimension = dimension

    def coord(self, c):
        if self.dimension <= 2:
            return c
        else:
            return c + [0]*(self.dimension-2)

    @coord_property
    def zerocoord(self):
        return [0,0]                  

    @coord_property
    def Dcoord(self):
        return [1,0]

    @coord_property
    def Tcoord(self):
        return [0,1]

    @coord_property
    def Xcoord(self):
        return [1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)]

    @coord_property
    def Ycoord(self):
        return [-1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a value to a property getter, and decorators will get clunky in a hurry. If you're using at lease 3.4, then you can reduce your line count using functools.partialmethod.

However, it's probably better to just keep your code the way it is, since "Explicit is better than implicit".

```
from functools import partialmethod

class BasisWrapped(object):

    def __init__(self, dimension):
        self.dimension = dimension

    def coord(self, c):
        if self.dimension <= 2:
            return c
        else:
            return c + [0]*(self.dimension-2)

    zerocoord = partialmethod(coord, [0, 0])
    d_coord = partialmethod(coord, [1, 0])
    t_coord = partialmethod(coord, [0, 1])
    x_coord = partialmethod(coord, [1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)])
    y_coord = partialmethod(coord, [-1./np.sqrt(2), 1./np.sqrt(2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the code is already quite elegant. **You shouldn't/can't make `coord` a property, because:**

- You won't be able to pass arguments to it, as a property is meant to be a "getter" for a (calculated?) field. `coord` behaves as a function and should hence be one.

If you are really just looking to reduce the size of your code, you can try an approach from the other answers, though I think it is not really necessary.

---

Aside: As I understand from your use case, you want to allow users to be able to call `coord` with a custom coordinate of their choice? If not, you can consider making it private by renaming it to `_coord`.